# How can I change the 'typ' of a token provided by Azure AD?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt, microsoft-graph-api, identityserver4

I have a project setup like this:

React frontend
-> authenticates against...
Identity Server
-> which redirects to...
A Microsoft login

I'm using a [Clients Credential Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) and it works great - the IS4 redirects to MS login, and then gets redirected with the access token back, which is then passed on to the React app.

Now, I've been tasked with creating a feature to change the user's password. I'm trying to do this by sending the old+new password to IS4, and then calling the MSGraphClient, but I couldn't make it work.

I've tried the `Username/Password provider`, because I have all the info needed, but I need to change stuff on the ActiveDirectory settings to make my app public. But even then, I don't like that solution.

I've also tried with the [On-behalf-of provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#on-behalf-of-provider), this is the code:

```
        var scopes = new[] { "User.Read",
            "Directory.AccessAsUser.All" };

        // Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
        // single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
        var tenantId = "~~";

        // Value from app registration
        var clientId = "~~";
        var clientSecret = "~~";
        
        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };

        // This is the incoming token to exchange using on-behalf-of flow
        var oboToken = HttpContext.Request.Headers.First(h => h.Key == "Authorization").Value.ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");


        var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .Build();

        // DelegateAuthenticationProvider is a simple auth provider implementation
        // that allows you to define an async function to retrieve a token
        // Alternatively, you can create a class that implements IAuthenticationProvider
        // for more complex scenarios
        var authProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) => {
            // Use Microsoft.Identity.Client to retrieve token
           var assertion = new UserAssertion(oboToken);
           var result = await cca.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, assertion).ExecuteAsync();

           request.Headers.Authorization =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
        });

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

And it kinds of work, because the request is made, but the server throws an error:

`AADSTS5002727: Invalid JWT header type specified. Allowed types: 'JWT','http://openid.net/specs/jwt/1.0'.`

I checked my token on JWT.io, and the `typ` is `at+jwt`... **Why? Why is MS sending me a type of token that it doesn't support? How can I change it from my side so it's a plain JWT?**

Thanks for any advice, and any other possible solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error "***AADSTS5002727: Invalid JWT header type specified. Allowed types: JWT,http ://openid.net/specs/jwt/1.0***" , please try the below if helpful:

- Please check the version of .Net core you are currently using to generate the token. Try using **.Net core 2.2 with IS4**.
- Try setting  `IdentityServerOptions.AccessTokenJwtType` to **empty string** or **`JWT`** on `IdentityServerOptions`.
- In the mentioned code, replace **`var oboToken`** variable directly with the value of token.

```cs
 var oboToken = "JWT_TOKEN_TO_EXCHANGE";
```

- Please **note** the below point from [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) :

> Don't attempt to validate or read tokens for any API you don't own,
> including the tokens in this example, in your code. Tokens for  Microsoft services can use a special format that will not validate as
> a JWT, and may also be encrypted for consumer (Microsoft account)
> users

- ***If still the error persists***, try upgrading clients to a new token validation library that works with the new style tokens.

**Please check whether the below links give you any pointer to resolve the issue:**

[JWT Token always Invalid · Issue #905 · openiddict/openiddict-core · GitHub](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/905)

[IdentityServer .Net Core 3.0 & Owin/Katana Token validation · Issue #3705 · IdentityServer/IdentityServer4 · GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3705)